# Rails version outputs lots Gem::LoadErrors — Rails installation broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Troubleshooting some weird Rails behaviour I checked my Rails version with `rails --version` and got this unsettling output:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find arel (~> 2.0.10)
amongst [Ascii85-1.0.1, RedCloth-4.2.8, RedCloth-4.2.7, SystemTimer-1.2.3, abstract-1.0.0,
actionmailer-3.0.10, actionmailer-3.0.9, actionpack-3.1.0, actionpack-3.0.10, actionpack-3.0.9,
actionwebservice-1.2.6, activemodel-3.1.0, activemodel-3.0.10, activemodel-3.0.9,
activerecord-3.0.10, activeresource-3.0.10, activesupport-3.1.0, activesupport-3.0.10,
activesupport-3.0.9, acts_as_ferret-0.5.2, addressable-2.2.6, always_verify_ssl_certificates-0.3.0,
arel-2.2.1, bcat-0.6.1, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.0, bson-1.3.1, bson_ext-1.3.1, builder-3.0.0, builder-2.1.2,
bundler-1.0.18, capistrano-2.8.0, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, cheat-1.3.0, colorize-0.5.8,
daemons-1.1.4, dbi-0.4.5, deadweight-0.2.1, deprecated-3.0.0, dnssd-2.0, easy_translate-0.2.1,
erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, eventmachine-0.12.10, faker-1.0.0, faraday-0.7.4,
faraday_middleware-0.7.0, fastthread-1.0.7, fcgi-0.8.8, feedbackmine-language_detector-0.1.2,
ferret-0.11.6, gem_plugin-0.2.3, haml-3.1.3, hashie-1.1.0, highline-1.6.2, hike-1.2.1,
hpricot-0.8.4, http_parser.rb-0.5.1, i18n-0.6.0, i18n-0.5.0, jk-ferret-0.11.8.3, json-1.5.3,
json_pure-1.5.3, language_detector-0.1.0, lastfm-cli-0.1.2-universal-darwin-9, libxml-ruby-2.2.1,
mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, markdown_prawn-0.0.4.pre, mime-types-1.16, mongo-1.3.1, mongo_mapper-0.9.1,
mongoid-2.2.0, mongrel-1.1.5, multi_json-1.0.3, multi_xml-0.3.0, multi_xml-0.2.2,
multipart-post-1.1.3, needle-1.3.0, net-scp-1.0.4, net-sftp-2.0.5, net-ssh-2.2.0,
net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, nokogiri-1.5.0, pdf-reader-0.10.0, plucky-0.3.8, polyglot-0.3.2,
prawn-0.11.1.pre, prowl-0.1.3, rack-1.3.2, rack-1.2.3, rack-1.2.1, rack-cache-1.0.3,
rack-mount-0.8.2, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.0.10,
railties-3.0.10, rake-0.9.2, random-0.2.1, rdoc-3.9.2, ruby-mysql-2.9.4, ruby-openid-2.1.8,
ruby-serialport-0.7.0, ruby-yadis-0.3.4, rubygems-update-1.8.10, rubygems-update-1.8.8,
sequel-3.26.0, shotgun-0.9, simple_oauth-0.1.5, sinatra-1.2.6, sinatra-1.0, sprockets-2.0.0,
sqlite3-1.3.4, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, termios-0.9.4, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10,
ttfunk-1.0.2, tweetstream-1.0.4, twitter-1.6.2, twitter-stream-0.1.14, tzinfo-0.3.29,
unsupervised-language-detection-0.0.6, whatlanguage-1.0.0, wtf_lang-0.3.1, xmpp4r-0.5,
yajl-ruby-0.7.9, yajl-ruby-0.7.7] (Gem::LoadError) from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `activate_dependencies' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate' from
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem' from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

I don't have any idea what the reason for this could be. I am under the slight impression that **something is broken**... Correct? How would you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Which `rubygems`, `bundler`, and what version of 1.8 Ruby are you using?

Comment: `gem -v`: 1.8.10, `bundler`: not installed :blush:, `ruby -v`: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Comment: @tadman: I found time to learn about, understand and install `bundler`, version  1.0.21 —